# Accessibility to take an two elements (icon and <a>) as one element

Tags: html, accessibility

I have a link with an icon before it. When making it accessibility complaint, we want it to be treated as a single element (Image 1) and not two elements(Image 2) which is the current scenario. Any leads on how to make this happen?

```
<div class="col-cta" style="height: 19px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-top: 0px;">
  <a href="#" class="content-link" title="Link">
    ::before
    Link
  </a>
</div>
```

Image 1: 
[image: element should be selected by screen reader like this]

Image 2:
[image: screen reader should NOT select it as two elements]

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="col-cta" style="height: 19px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-top: 0px;">
  <a href="#" class="content-link" aria-label="Link to xx">
    <span role="presentation">&#8250;&#160;</span>Link
  </a>
</div>
```

### Explanation

- Use the `aria-label` attribute on the hyperlink and give it an accessible name.
- The `<span>` which contains the icon has been given the [`role=presentation`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#presentation) which is used when elements need to be in the DOM, but the semantics of them are inaccurate or unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Accessibility to take two elements (icon and a tag) as one element you can make an accordion to solve this issues.
Here the documentation link: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        /* Toggle between adding and removing the "active" class,
        to highlight the button that controls the panel */
        this.classList.toggle("active");

        /* Toggle between hiding and showing the active panel */
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.display === "block") {
            panel.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            panel.style.display = "block";
        }
    });
}
```

```css
.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

/* Add a background color to the button if it is clicked on (add the .active class with JS), and when you move the mouse over it (hover) */
.active, .accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the accordion panel. Note: hidden by default */
.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.accordion, i {
        float: right;

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<button class="accordion">Image 1 <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i> </button>
<div class="panel">
  <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Image 2 <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i> </button>
<div class="panel">
  <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Image 3 <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i> </button>
<div class="panel">
  <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Mridul, thanks for the answer but I don't want to convert the simple link into an accordion and change it visually.

Answer (score 0):

There's no **accessibility** problem to solve here.

> I have a link with an icon before it. When making it accessibility
>   complaint, we want it to be treated as a single element

```
<div class="col-cta" style="height: 19px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-top: 0px;">
  <a href="#" class="content-link" title="Link">
    ::before
    Link
  </a>
</div>
```

The icon and the link text are *already the same element*.  The `::before` pseudo-element is semantically part of the `<a>` element's content. Accessibility-wise this is just a link, with the accessible name "Link". There isn't anything wrong with this at all, if that's all the information you need to convey.  (Although the `title="Link"` attribute serves no purpose here, and should be removed.)

The wrapper `<div>` is a red herring here; as far as accessibility is concerned, it plays no part at all.

Does the icon convey any important information, which isn't in the link text? If so, it needs a text alternative. Use an `<img alt="whatever" src="icon.png">` or `<span class="icon visually-hidden>whatever</span>` nested inside the `<a>`. Note that CSS generated content in a `::before` pseudo-element forms part of the link's [accessible name calculation](https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/), so beware of using punctuation/emoji characters here as they may be announced by a screen reader.  For instance, `a::before { content: '>'; }` may lead to screen readers announcing "greater than" as part of the link name, which probably isn't what you intended to convey.

The `a::before` pseudo-element also appears visually *inside* the `<a>` element's content box.  So for purposes of the focus outline it is already one box.  The dev-tools screenshots are perhaps misleading in this regard. Try focusing your link by pressing TAB on a keyboard; the focus outline should enclose the `::before` pseudo-element too.  Here's a snippet which demonstrates this:

```css
a {
  background-color: lightgray;
  font-size: 1.2em; 
}

a:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}

a:focus {
 outline: 2px dotted red; 
}

a::before,
a::after {
   /* Star icon from https://github.com/ry5n/libricons
    * It has an MIT license.
    */
   content: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}
```

```html
<p>Q: Do <code>::before</code> and <code>::after</code> pseudo-elements appear inside the element's content box?</p>
<a href="#">Geronimo</a>
<p>A: Yes they do.  See the background colour, and focus outline.</p>
```